# CSV data source does not support null data type in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to save dataframe into file using the pyspark method but I am getting above error. IThe same code I am trying in python 2.7, there it is working but python 3.6 it is not working. Could anyone help me what I am doing wrong?
I am adding the schema details of the table.

I am trying below code:

```
df.repartition(1).write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').mode('overwrite').save(output_path,quote='',escape='\"', sep='|',header='True',nullValue=None)
```

PrintSchema():

```
|-- fact_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Active_Flag: null (nullable = true)
 |-- Project_End_Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Project_Effective_Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Notification to Implement Issued Clarification: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Notification to Implement Issued: string (nullable = true)
 |-- pERC Reconsideration Meeting Clarification: string (nullable = true)
 |-- pERC Reconsideration Meeting: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Feedback Deadline Clarification: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Feedback Deadline: string (nullable = true)
 |-- pERC Meeting Clarification: string (nullable = true)
 |-- pERC Meeting: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Check-point meeting Clarification: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Check-point meeting: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Patient Advocacy Group Input Deadline Clarification: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Patient Advocacy Group Input Deadline: string (nullable = true)
 |-- NOC Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Pre NOC Submission: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Status Clarification: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Review Status: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Prioritization: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Tumour Type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Submitter: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Sponsor: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Funding Request: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CADTH review report(s) posted: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Deadline for sponsor to submit redaction requests on draft CADTH review report(s): string (nullable = true)
 |-- Reconsideration Requested Clarification: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Reconsideration Requested: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Final Recommendation Issued Clarification: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Final recommendation posted: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Final Recommendation Sent to Drug Plans and Manufacturer Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Reconsideration Meeting Date Clarification: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Reconsideration Meeting Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Embargo period ended clarification: null (nullable = true)
 |-- Embargo period ended: null (nullable = true)
 |-- Embargo Period Date Clarification: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Embargo Period Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Final recommendation issued to sponsor and drug plans Clarification: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Final recommendation issued to sponsor and drug plans: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CDEC Meeting Date Clarification: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CDEC Meeting Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Redaction Response from Manufacturer on Report Received by CADTH Date Clarification: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Redaction Response from Manufacturer on Report Received by CADTH Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Comments from Manufacturers on Reviewer's Report Date Clarification: null (nullable = true)
 |-- Comments from Manufacturers on Reviewer's Report Date: null (nullable = true)
 |-- Deadline for sponsors comments Clarification: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Deadline for sponsors comments: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CADTH Reviewers Report sent to Manufacturer Date Clarification: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CADTH Reviewers Report sent to Manufacturer Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Patient Group Input Summary Comment Received Date Clarification: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Patient Group Input Summary Comment Received Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Patient input summary sent for review to patient input groups clarification: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Patient input summary sent for review to patient input groups: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Patient Group Input Submission Received Date Clarification: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Patient Group Input Submission Received Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Call for Patient Input Date Clarification: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Call for Patient Input Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Submission Deemed Complete Actual Date Clarification: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Submission Deemed Complete Actual Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Submission Deemed Complete Target Date Clarification: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Submission Deemed Complete Target Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Patient group input closed clarification: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Patient group input closed: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Fee Schedule: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Recommendation Type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Initial Recommendation Issued Clarification: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Recommendation Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Companion Diagnostics: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Submission Type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Review initiated: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Submission Date Clarification: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Submission accepted: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Submission received: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Manufacture_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Biosimilar: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Manufacturer Requested Reimbursement Criteria: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Thrc_area_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Generic_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- BRAND_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- indication_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Strength: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Project Number: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Modified Time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Published Time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Updated Time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Program Name: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @think-maths, the headline of the question is the error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can cast the null column to string type before writing:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import NullType
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# Check each column type. If it's nulltype, cast to string type,
# else keep the original column.

df2 = df.select([
    F.lit(None).cast('string').alias(i.name)
    if isinstance(i.dataType, NullType)
    else i.name
    for i in df.schema
])

df2.repartition(1).write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').mode('overwrite').save(output_path, quote='', escape='\"', sep='|', header='True', nullValue=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

the question thread shared by @blackbishop does answer your question you have your `Active_Flag` and `Embargo period ended` as `null` in schema.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
df.withColumn('Active_Flag', lit(None).cast(StringType))
  .withColumn('Embargo period ended', lit(None).cast(StringType))
```